# Angular 4 - ngFor dropdown / select-options is very slow on IE11, how to optimize ngDoCheck execution?

Tags: angular, performance, internet-explorer-11

We have a dropdown list that receive 3K+ data to be listed.

```html
<select class="form-control" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="employeeJobCode.JobCode.Id" name="JobCode" [ngClass]="{'alert-danger': JobCode.errors && (JobCode.dirty || JobCode.touched)}" #JobCode="ngModel" required>
<option [value]=""></option>
<option *ngFor="let dropDownValue of jobCodeListData" [value]="dropDownValue.Id">{{ dropDownValue.FullName }}</option>
</select>
```

When we expand the dropdown it renders all 3K+ items in the list. 
This action takes more than 40 seconds to complete on IE11.

On checking the profiler data, we found that NgForOf.prototype.ngDoCheck is taking almost 36 seconds, as can be seen in pic -

[ngFor slowness in IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNDoV.png)

What may be the reason that ngDoCheck is so slow?
How can we optimize this performance?

Comment: Use the OnPush change detection strategy to tell Angular 2 there have been no changes.

Comment: You loading all those items before you open the select?

Comment: Yes, @Swoox, data is loaded.